# Replace javascript in database with phpmysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Realated to this topic : [Why do I receive an error in SQL when trying to find and replace javascript within a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52574689/why-do-i-receive-an-error-in-sql-when-trying-to-find-and-replace-javascript-with)

But didn't work for me. I have the same issue.

I tried:

```
SELECT
  `post_content`,
  REPLACE(`post_content`, '<script src=''https://hotopponents.site/site.js'' type=''text/javascript''></script>', ''), 
  COUNT(*)
FROM `db742664123`.`VUjlspmhposts` 
WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%<script src=''https://hotopponents.site/site.js'' type=''text/javascript''></script>%' COLLATE utf8_bin 
GROUP BY `post_content`
ORDER BY `post_content` ASC
```

Changed the db name and the table. But nothing happened, it returned 0.

Just want to erase these malicious code at once from the whole database.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: MySQL returned zero result (zero line ). (Query took 0.0104 sec.)

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '<script src=''https://hotopponents.site/site.js'' type=''text/javascript''></script>', '')
```